# Unable to delete specific number in a Contact in Android

Tags: android, selection, android-contentprovider, contacts, android-contacts

I'm working on an application in which I should be able to access all the contacts, able to update or delete the numbers in any contact.

I want to delete few numbers in a contact. I'm using batchOperations to perform delete operation.

```
phone = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ?";
String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{Integer.toString(rawContactId), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(id)};
batchOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(phone, phoneArgs).build());
this.mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch("com.android.contacts", batchOperations);
batchOperations.clear();
```

I'm using this part of code to delete a specific number from the Contact. Using debugger, for a sample delete operation, I found the values as:

```
raw_contact_id = 4093
id = 21579
```

These values correspond to specific number("+814444444444") in a group of numbers in a sample contact.(Please refer image below)
[image: Image of Contact]

But still the number is not getting deleted. I've been trying to figure it out for the last couple of hours but couldn't solve it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of supplying selection + selectionArgs, you can build a uri of the specific item you want to delete, like so:

```
Uri phoneUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Data.CONTENT_URI, phoneId);
batchOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(phoneUri).build());
```

A couple of other notes:

1. Always check the return value of `applyBatch`, if it's false, there's some issue with your code / permissions.
2. Use the constant `ContactsContract.AUTHORITY` instead of the hard-coded string "com.android.contacts".

Another reason for the observed behavior is that the phone "+814444444444" is stored on multiple `RawContacts` aggregated into a single contact.
In which case even when you properly delete the row from RawContact A, the contact profile would still get the number from RawContact B.

This is especially true for phone numbers when certain apps such as `Whatsapp` are installed which tend to copy over contacts' phone numbers to a separate `RawContact` under their own account.

If that's the issue you'll need to delete the phone number from ALL the contact's `RawContacts` holding that phone.

**EDIT**

Here's how to dump all phone numbers that belong to a specific contact, along with the raw-contact that holds them:

```
String selection = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { contactId.toString(), Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
String[] projection = new String[] { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Data.DATA1 };

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, projection);
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cur);
```

Also, note that a `rawContactId` is not an integer, it's a long.

Comment: I checked and "applyBatch" is working perfectly. There is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: did you check if that data row might be coming from other raw contacts?

Comment: Can you tell me how to check that? I have checked adding a "newInsert" statement and it is working fine. But newDelete is not working

Comment: I did one thing. I turned off GMail sync in contacts and I created a new contact. It is stored in device. Now, when I do delete from the app, i have built, it is working perfectly fine. It is deleting from native contacts too. But when Gmail Sync is on, it is not deleting. Deleted number is still there in native contacts.